# Why does "sp.js" load only when I am editing a web part page?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, client-object-model

I have created a page and would like to use some functions that require sp.js to be loaded, but it never seems to load unless I am editid the page (Site Actions -> Edit Page).

Trying to find the error I have modified my code to look like this:

```
console.log("1");
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadConstants, "sp.js");        
console.log("3");   

function loadConstants() {

    console.log("2");

}
```

When I am simply visiting the page, this is the output:

```
"1"
"3"
```

When I click on Site Actions, and then click Edit Page, when the page loads this is the output:

```
"1"
"3"
"2"
```

Comment: maybe it's only loaded when it's needed?

Comment: But shouldn't it load anyway if I say "ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadConstants, "sp.js")" ?
By the way, this is just some code I wrote for debugging; in reality I need to get items from a list using SharePoint 2010 CSOM.

Comment: I think it does what it should, the ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded waits until sp.js is loaded before it executes your method. It does not force to load the script.

Comment: So you think "sp.js" needs to be loaded when I am editing the page and not when I am simply visiting it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

user1901384 is correct, ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded won't load it, it will just check to see if it has been loaded. Take a look at this code sample ([full page here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245759%28v=office.15%29.aspx)). You don't need the `clientContext` part, what you're looking for is `SP.SOD.executeFunc()` but I left in the `clientContext` because you might find that helpful as well. Put your `console.log('2')` inside `sharePointReady()` and you should see it fire.

```
var clientContext;
var website;

// Make sure the SharePoint script file 'sp.js' is loaded before your
// code runs.
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);

// Create an instance of the current context.
function sharePointReady() {
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    website = clientContext.get_web();

    clientContext.load(website);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded, onRequestFailed);
}
function onRequestSucceeded() {
    alert(website.get_url());
}
function onRequestFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Error: ' + args.get_message());
}
```

Comment: SP.SOD.executeFunc is not working for me... facing the same issue...tried with ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded, but no luck...Please help...

Answer (score 11):

As a part of the new Minimal Download Strategy (MDS) the `sp.js` library  is not loaded until explicitly called in SharePoint 2013.

Your case is pretty common, for example for a publishing pages, where `sp.js` library is loaded in the edit mode but not in the display mode.

### Solution

Prefer `SP.SOD.executeFunc` over `SP.SOD.ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` method since it supports the *load on demand* scripts:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){

 //your code goes here...

});
```

Comment: Just now I noticed that I have forgotten to point out that I am using SharePoint 2010. But in the meantime I have done just what you suggested and it worked.
Is the reason that `sp.js` can sometimes be loaded in edit mode but not in display because pages are opened in edit mode very rarely?